# Twilio set variable widgets

Tags: python, twilio, twilio-api, twilio-studio

I am pretty new to python and Twilio, so thanks in advance.

I have set up a Twilio flow to collect consumer experience data via an automated call. The call uses split by voice, and in the event of an error split by digits (both keystrokes and speech are acceptable inputs to both arms). I need to be able to extract the responses to these questions. I believe I can use set variable widgets in my studio flow to achieve this. However the documentation here has lost me - https://www.twilio.com/docs/studio/widget-library/set-variables.

Is this possible? What do I need to enter into the widget to collect the response? where do I place the widget? and where is the data then stored for me to use the API to extract it?

Again - thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use the Studio [set variables widget](https://www.twilio.com/docs/studio/widget-library/set-variables) but could if you want to assemble all the results into global variables for your flow. Take a look at the below webinar which does a quick overview on Studio, it should help explain how you can use `{{variable}}` syntax to extract the `Digits` and `SpeechResult` from the respective widgets ([Gather Input on Call Widget](https://www.twilio.com/docs/studio/widget-library/gather-input-call)).

Press 1 For Sales: Building an IVR for Your Startup

(Watch Replay)

https://www.crowdcast.io/e/press-1-for-sales (starts at timecode 12:50)